# iOS - App not showing good in 4 inches display simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, screen

I don't have an iPhone 5 for testing my apps. I developed an app for iOS 5, so I'm not using the autolayout feature. When I try my app on the 4 inches display of the simulator I don't see a black space over and under my app as expected, it try to fill all the screen and it's not showing good... How can I fix that? Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem? "not showing good" doesn't tell us much. Include a screenshot or two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the *autoresizing mask* of your views appropriately (no, this is not the same as autolayout and it's supported in every version of iOS).

You can do this directly in Interface Builder (your xib file or storyboard), see the screenshot below. You basically have to click on the red arrows/bars until the view resizes in a way that makes sense for your app.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I solved in this way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you see a default-568h@2x.png in your project folder, delete it. That will tell the iPhone to set your app to the iPhone 4 screen size when viewing in iPhone 5 if all your views are iPhone 4 screen size.

However, as of May 1st, this will not be accepted in the AppStore.

Comment: ...which is a great way to get your app rejected.

Comment: No. It is a legitimate solution.

Comment: Ok, I don't want to be rejected, so what can I do?

Comment: @StefanoGiacone Fix your app to work on 4" screens. Apple doesn't allow apps using the black bars anymore. There's many tutorials out on the internet (and on SO) for how to handle these sorts of scenarios without Auto Layout.

Comment: @HM1 No, it's not, see here: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=3212013b

Comment: @Stefano, I have 2 apps in the AppStore using that... however I just realized it was submitted before Apple's new requirement of having iPhone Screen size support from May 1st. What's stopping you from making it 4" compatible?

Comment: @omz... Sorry, I forgot about the new requirement starting May 1st. Before then, it was a legit solution.

Comment: @Stefano, I would check for each of the uiviews and subviews to see where they are anchored and change it depending on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

For every object on your display, make sure the autolayout settings are correct so that the buttons, images, etc stretch to fill the screen and maintain their proportions.

The main image is probably not stretching because you haven't told it to maintain alignment to the superview at the bottom (which will stretch it). You can tell bcause the top space on the second image is exactly double the space in the first (which means it is aligned to the top); but he bottom isn't, so it is causing a gap.

Make sure you habe the longer @2x image created as well.

Also as an FYI, you should develop the apps using the 3.5 inch setting on storyboard, and nsure autolayout and proper images @2x will expand.

Comment: my target it's iOS5, I can't use autolayout...

Comment: Sorry to hear that... Then you will need to adjust the layout settings, I think i solved this a while back using redraw as opposed to scale to fill